# Iterate through date ranges without using libraries - Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

Hi I want to iterate through a date range without using any libraries. I want to start on 18/01/2005(want to format it to yyyy/M/d) and iterate in day intervals until the current date. I have formatted the start date, but I dont know how I can add it to a calendar object and iterate. I was wondering if anyone can help. Thanks

```
String newstr = "2005/01/18";
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Date date = format1.parse(newstr);
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
while (someCondition(calendar)) {
    doSomethingWithTheCalendar(calendar);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a string into a `Date` object or format a `Date` object into a string.

Use class `Calendar` for date arithmetic. It has an `add` method to advance the calendar, for example with a day.

See the API documentation of the classes mentioned above.

Alternatively, use the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library, which makes these things easier. (The `Date` and `Calendar` classes in the standard Java API have a number of design issues and are not as powerful as Joda Time).